# Mongoose Schema with JSON object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema defined like this:

```
var things = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    properties: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            function(v) {
                if (typeof v !== 'object') return false
                return true
            },
            message: 'Not a valid object'
        }
    }
})
```

According to the mongoose documentation there is no **Object** type.

How can I define the *properties* parameter as object type?

So that I can post the following:

```
properties: {"prop1": "property one", "prop2": "property two"}
```

An how can I validate that the posted value is and Object and not and array?

I used the schema as indicated but my validation don't seem to work. I can pass and array and the data is saved.

Comment: An array is an object `> typeof [] => 'object'`